# the root filesystem /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv requires a manual fsck

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck

I have a server running on Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 LTS.

Sometimes the os goes in read-only mode and I have to do a "sudo reboot" and every time it reboots i get this error:

"the root filesystem /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv requires a manual fsck"

And after manually doing fsck on that filesystem the pc boots up.

Does somebody know what it could be causing this issue?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: The disk is failing.

Comment: There is always a reason as to why a *file-system* flips from RW to RO, have you looked at your logs to explore why? and checked the health of your drive(s)?   You maybe ignoring the *warning signs* of your system.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: I've used the link you sent to me and i got these results: Num 1, Test_Description Short offline, Status Completed: read failure, Remaining 90%, LifeTime(hours) 9738, LBA_of_first_error 33302496